# Skip web authentication of gmail api

Tags: .net, gmail-api

I am developing the Email Application to read the specific mail from Gmail for that I am using the below code.

```
 using (var stream = new FileStream(userCredentialLocation + CredentialsJasonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
      string credPath = userCredentialLocation;    
      credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gaf-gSuite.json");
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

            }
```

But It's launching Gmail application to give the access but I want to skip the human interaction like give command line access.

Please, anyone, help me.

Answer (score 0):

That's an inherent part of the flow in authorizing your app:

> Authorizing Your App with Gmail All requests to the Gmail API must be
>   authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the [OAuth 2.0
>   protocol](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for
>   authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data.
>   You can also use Google+ Sign-in to provide a "sign-in with Google"
>   authentication method for your app.

You can try that [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in) alternative if it works for you.